# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Xms256M

Tags: java, eclipse, server, websphere, websphere-8

While starting the WAS 8.5 server I am getting the below error message in the console. For more than one hour it progress status is starting...
I believe there is some configuration issue but not able to find it. I am using java 7 and Eclipse Kepler.

Console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<verbosegc xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/j9/verbosegc" version="R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580_CMPRSS">

<initialized id="1" timestamp="2016-05-31T11:39:12.001">
<attribute name="gcPolicy" value="-Xgcpolicy:gencon" />
<attribute name="maxHeapSize" value="0x20000000" />
<attribute name="initialHeapSize" value="0x20000000" />
<attribute name="compressedRefs" value="true" />
<attribute name="compressedRefsDisplacement" value="0x0" />
<attribute name="compressedRefsShift" value="0x0" />
<attribute name="pageSize" value="0x1000" />
<attribute name="pageType" value="not used" />
<attribute name="requestedPageSize" value="0x1000" />
<attribute name="requestedPageType" value="not used" />
<attribute name="gcthreads" value="4" />
<attribute name="numaNodes" value="0" />
<system>
    <attribute name="physicalMemory" value="8482004992" />
    <attribute name="numCPUs" value="4" />
    <attribute name="architecture" value="amd64" />
    <attribute name="os" value="Windows 8" />
    <attribute name="osVersion" value="6.2" />
</system>
<vmargs>
    <vmarg name="-Xoptionsfile=C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs\options.default" />
    <vmarg name="-Xlockword:mode=default,noLockword=java/lang/String,noLockword=java/util/MapEntry,noLockword=java/util/HashMap$Entry,noLockword..." />
    <vmarg name="-Xjcl:jclscar_26" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin" />
    <vmarg name="-Dsun.boot.library.path=C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.library.path=C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WAS8\lib\native\..." />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.home=C:\WAS8\java\jre" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\WAS8\java\jre\lib\ext" />
    <vmarg name="-Duser.dir=C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01\bin" />
    <vmarg name="_j2se_j9=1119744" value="00007FF8EEE5BC40" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.runtime.version=pwa6460_26sr7fp1ifx-20140220_01 (SR7 FP1)" />
    <vmarg name="-Dconsole.encoding=Cp437" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.class.path=." />
    <vmarg name="-Declipse.security" />
    <vmarg name="-Dosgi.install.area=C:\WAS8" />
    <vmarg name="-Dosgi.configuration.area=C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01/servers/server1/configuration" />
    <vmarg name="-Dosgi.framework.extensions=com.ibm.cds,com.ibm.ws.eclipse.adaptors" />
    <vmarg name="-Xshareclasses:name=webspherev85_1.6_64,nonFatal" />
    <vmarg name="-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=250" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.xtq.processor.overrideSecureProcessing=true" />
    <vmarg name="-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\WAS8/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.class.path=C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\WAS8/properties;C:\WAS8/lib/startup.jar;C:\WAS8/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\..." />
    <vmarg name="-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=*" />
    <vmarg name="-Dibm.websphere.internalClassAccessMode=allow" />
    <vmarg name="-verbose:gc" />
    <vmarg name="-Xms512m" />
    <vmarg name="-Xcompressedrefs" />
    <vmarg name="-Xscmaxaot4M" />
    <vmarg name="-Xscmx60M" />
    <vmarg name="-Xquickstart" />
    <vmarg name="-Dws.ext.dirs=C:\WAS8/java/lib;C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\WAS8/classes;C:\WAS8/lib;C:\WAS8/installedChannels;C:\WAS8/..." />
    <vmarg name="-Dderby.system.home=C:\WAS8/derby" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.itp.location=C:\WAS8/bin" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true" />
    <vmarg name="-Duser.install.root=C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\WAS8/tivoli/tam;C:\WAS8/java/jre/lib/ext" />
    <vmarg name="-Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.ibm.ws.management.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder" />
    <vmarg name="-Dpython.cachedir=C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01/temp/cachedir" />
    <vmarg name="-Dwas.install.root=C:\WAS8" />
    <vmarg name="-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager" />
    <vmarg name="-Dserver.root=C:\WAS8\profiles\AppSrv01" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.security.jgss.debug=off" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug=off" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.pull_notification_timeout=120000" />
    <vmarg name="-Dcom.ibm.websphere.ejbcontainer.defaultStatefulSessionTimeout=35" />
    <vmarg name="-Xquickstart" />
    <vmarg name="-Dsun.java.command=Xms256M -Xmx1024M -Djava.library.path=C:\WAS8/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\..." />
    <vmarg name="-Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD" />
    <vmarg name="_port_library" value="00007FF8EEE5A920" />
    <vmarg name="_bfu_java" value="00007FF8EEE5BF10" />
    <vmarg name="_org.apache.harmony.vmi.portlib" value="000000000021EF60" />
</vmargs>
</initialized>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Xms256M
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Xms256M
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:703)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:682)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
</verbosegc>

Could not find the main class: Xms256M.  Program will exit.
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/WAS8/java/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:UseSSE=4
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=6
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A simple missing minus sign:

```
<vmarg name="-Dsun.java.command=-Xms256M -Xmx1024M -Djava.library.path=C:\WAS8/lib/native/win/x86_64/;C:\WAS8\java\jre\bin\compressedrefs;C:\..." />
```

Note the minus sign in `-Xms256M` ...

Comment: Okay. Where to update minus sign before `Xms256M` to reflect it properly?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The shown line is exactly the line where you have to put the minus sign.

Comment: My question is: Is this a configuration file for WAS? It is the output in my console. I am not able to find the physical location where I have to update the minus sign.

Comment: The value side of it has spaces. Perhaps they need to be quoted themselves or the spaces need to be escaped somehow.